# How to Parse a Text Which is Outside of Tag

Tags: python, selenium, parsing, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I'm parsing a text, which every word is made into a link. Problem is that punctuation marks aren't the content of that tags `<a>`, they just lie outside the tags, so I don't know what to do to get punctuation marks too.

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="#">Lorem</a>
        ", "
        <a href="#">Ipsum</a>
        ": "
        <a href="#">dolor</a>
        "."
      </td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="#">sit</a>
        "? '"
        <a href="#">amet</a>
        "' "
        <a href="#">consectetur</a>
        "..."
      </td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="#">adipisicing</a>
        "-"
        <a href="#">elit</a>
        "; "
        <a href="#">Molestias</a>
        "!"
      </td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

here's the parser

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="...")
driver.get(url=...)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

words = []
for tableRows in soup.select("table > tbody > tr"):
  for word in tableRows.find("td").select("a"):
    words.append(word.text)

print(words)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text content between `a` tag elements belongs to the parent `td` element itself.
You can directly grab text from `td` elements, as following:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="...")
driver.get(url=...)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

words = []
for tableRow in soup.select("table > tbody > tr"):
  words.append(tableRow.text)

print(words)
```

**UPD**
In case you want to get punctuation marks as separated objects you can split the table row text by spaces. The following code should do that + remove leading and trailing spaces.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="...")
driver.get(url=...)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

words = []
for tableRow in soup.select("table > tbody > tr"):
  tableRowtext = tableRow.text
  rowTexts = [x.strip() for x in tableRowtext.split(' ')]
  words.append(rowTexts)

print(words)
```

Comment: I need to get both words and punctuation marks: `['Lorem', ',', 'Ipsum', ':', 'dolor', '.']`

Comment: Thank you very much. However, this didn't solve my problem everywhere. Often `<td>` also contains other tags with text inside, that aren't needed. I only need texts from `<a>` tags and texts without a tag. `<td><b>wrongText</b> <a>rightText</a> "," <sup>wrongText</sup></td>`

Comment: If so please open a new question for that. I think I can help there

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74337881/20431669

Comment: I see. I see someone already answered there. In case this not resolved your problem let me know

Comment: Yeah, it didn't help so I edited the question, he misunderstood the problem