# Scrapping Text Content of a Tag, But Not Text from Other Tags Inside of First

Tags: python, selenium, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to get the text from first `<td>` element of each `<tr>`. But not all the text, only the one inside tags `<a>` and outside of any other tag. I wrote examples of necessary text as "yyy"/"y" and examples of not necessary as "zzz"

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <b>zzz</b>
        <a href="#">yyy</a>
        "y"
        <a href="#">yyy</a>
        <sup>zzz</sup>
        <a href="#">yyy</a>
        <a href="#">yyy</a>
        "y"
      </td>
      <td>
        zzzzz
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here what I have at the moment

```py
words = []
for tableRows in soup.select("table > tbody > tr"):
  tableData = tableRows.find("td").text
  text = [word.strip() for word in tableData.split(' ')]
  words.append(text)
print(words)
```

But this code is parsing all the text from `<td>`: `["zzz", "yyyy", "yyyy", "zzz", "yyyy"]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag, NavigableString

html_doc = """\
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <b>zzz</b>
        <a href="#">yyy</a>
        "y"
        <a href="#">yyy</a>
        <sup>zzz</sup>
        <a href="#">yyy</a>
        <a href="#">yyy</a>
        "y"
      </td>
      <td>
        zzzzz
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

for td in soup.select("td:nth-of-type(1)"):
    for c in td.contents:
        if isinstance(c, Tag) and c.name == "a":
            print(c.text.strip())
        elif isinstance(c, NavigableString):
            c = c.strip()
            if c:
                print(c)
```

Prints:

```
yyy
"y"
yyy
yyy
yyy
"y"
```

---

- `soup.select("td:nth-of-type(1)")` selects just first `<td>`.
- then we iterate over `.contents` of this `<td>`
- `if isinstance(c, Tag) and c.name == "a"` checks if the content is `Tag` and the name of the `Tag` is `<a>`
- `if isinstance(c, NavigableString)` checks if the content is plain string.

Comment: NameError: name 'Tag' is not defined

Comment: Okay, this worked, but I deleted `isinstance(c, Tag) and` from if and changed `isinstance(c, NavigableString)` from elif into `isinstance(c, str)`. A accepted your answer, but please, edit it because as I wrote your code gives NameError

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, use the `children` of `td` tag.
Then check child having name `a` of None.
Then check if child having text then append.

```
words = []

for item in soup.select("table > tbody > tr"):
    for child in item.td.children:        
        if child.name=='a' or child.name==None:
           if child.text.strip():
              words.append(child.text.strip())
print(words)
```

**Output:**

```
['yyy', '"y"', 'yyy', 'yyy', 'yyy', '"y"']
```